# setImage not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a problem setting an image. I have a delegate telling me when an image is taken from the imagePickerController. It sends it to the owner controller, and then I try to set the image on another controller. It all seems like it should be working... but whenever I the view shows up, the image isn't there. Here's the code:

```
// this gets called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera
// it is in the viewController in charge of grabbing an image (.m file)
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if(self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate didAcquirePicture:image];
    }
}


//This is in the controller .m file
- (void)didAcquirePicture:(UIImage *)picture 
{
    if(picture != Nil)
    {
        self.photoEditView = [[PhotoEditViewController alloc] init];
        [self.photoPicker.imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [self.photoEditView.imageView setImage:picture];
        [self presentModalViewController: self.photoEditView animated:NO];

    }
}

//this is the photoEditViewController .h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PhotoEditViewController;

@protocol PhotoEditViewControllerDelegate
@end


@interface PhotoEditViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (retain) UIImageView *imageView;


@end

//this is the photoEditView .m file
#import "PhotoEditViewController.h"

@implementation PhotoEditViewController

@synthesize imageView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [imageView dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: In `- imagePickerController::`, are you positive `image` is not `nil`? You're checking against `nil` (or rather `Nil`) in `- didAcquirePicture:`, but you don't give yourself even an `NSLog` to verify if the desired code is being executed. I'd double check for a `nil` value before going any further.

Comment: Just for info, and even it will expand to the same thing, Nil is intended to represent NULL on classes, not on object... Use nil instead, for improved readability...

Comment: Not sure about the image issue, but I see some issues in the code.  In the dealloc method you implemented, release your instance variables and then call [super dealloc].  This next part is not an issue if you aren't declaring photoEditView as @property (retain, etc). self.photoEditView = [[PhotoEditViewController alloc] init] will leak if the property retains it when it set... you could use self.photoEditView = [[[PhotoEditViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; to avoid that memory leak if the property set to retain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIGURED OUT THE PROBLEM**

---

It turns out that my image was being deallocated before the view completely loaded and control was given back to the event loop. It was a timing problem, and I was stupid not to see it. So, I made a UIImage variable in my .h file called tempImage, then I just put this in -(void)viewDidLoad:

```
self.imageView.image = tempImage;
```

This is what my didAcquirePicture method looks like now:

```
- (void)didAcquirePicture:(UIImage *)picture 
{
    if(picture != nil)
    {
        self.photoEditView = [[[PhotoEditViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        self.photoEditView.tempImage = picture;

        [self.photoPicker.imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController: self.photoEditView animated:NO];
        [self.photoEditView setupStache];
    }
}
```

I'm basically just saving the image, then when I KNOW the view is loaded, I set the image in my viewDidLoad. Thanks everyone for helping me arrive at the final answer!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's possible the image is being released when you dismiss the imagePickerController, before you assign it to the imageView. If so, you could fix it with

`[[picture retain] autorelease];`

As mentioned, test against `nil` not `Nil`. Also, it's better to use `[self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(didAcquirePicture)];` — remember that it's safe to send messages to `nil`.